# Page_Load keeps running more than once VB.net

Tags: vb.net

This is the code. The Page_Load keeps firing and I need it to only run once.
When i debug, my page_load keeps firing up

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="False" CodeBehind="helloworld.aspx.vb" 
    Inherits="WebApplication9.helloworld" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubsribe" runat="server" Text="Subscribe" />
    
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="281px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="303px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
    
    </div>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server">
        </asp:Timer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


VB Code:

Imports System
Imports uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt
Imports uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages
Imports System.Text.Encoding

Public Class helloworld
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Publisher As MqttClient = Nothing
    Private Subscriber As MqttClient = Nothing
    Private msgTime As String = ""
    Private msgDate As String = ""
    Const TIME_ID As String = "/CPM/Time"
    Const DATE_ID As String = "/CPM/Date"
    Const MATH_ID As String = "3.14"
    Const DefaultInteger As Integer = 100
    Const MyLong As Long = 45L
    Const MySingle As Single = 45.55!
    Const MyCharacter As Char = "a"c
```

I have tried to change the Page_Load handles but it still doesn't work

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Publisher = New MqttClient("telemetry")
        Dim b As Boolean = CBool(Publisher.Connect(Guid.NewGuid.ToString))
        Timer1.Interval = 2000
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Dim dt As DateTime = Now
        TextBox1.Text = dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")
        TextBox3.Text = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Dim ppreturn1 As UShort = Publisher.Publish(TIME_ID, UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
        Dim ppreturn2 As UShort = Publisher.Publish(DATE_ID, UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox3.Text))
        'Dim ppreturn3 As UShort = Publisher.Publish(MATH_ID, UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
        'Dim ppreturn4 As UShort = Publisher.Publish(DefaultInteger, UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
        'Dim ppreturn5 As UShort = Publisher.Publish(MyLong, UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
        'Dim ppreturn6 As UShort = Publisher.Publish(MySingle, UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
        ' Dim ppreturn7 As UShort = Publisher.Publish(MyCharacter, UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))

        TextBox2.Text = msgTime
        'TextBox3.Text = message
        TextBox4.Text = msgDate
        'TextBox5.Text = message
        'TextBox6.Text = message
        'TextBox7.Text = message
        'TextBox8.Text = message




    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSubsribe_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubsribe.Click
        Subscriber = New MqttClient("telemetry")
        Dim b As Byte = Subscriber.Connect(Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
        btnSubsribe.Enabled = False
        Subscriber.Subscribe(New String() {DATE_ID, TIME_ID}, New Byte() {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE})
        'Subscriber.Subscribe(New String() {TIME_ID}, New Byte() {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE})
        AddHandler Subscriber.MqttMsgPublishReceived, AddressOf Client_recievedMessage

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Client_recievedMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MqttMsgPublishEventArgs)
        Dim s As String = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetString(e.Message)

        Select Case e.Topic
            Case DATE_ID
                msgDate = s
            Case TIME_ID
                msgTime = s
        End Select

    End Sub


End Class
```

This is a timer application that runs on the internet. It used the timer tool that is used in visual studios. Asp.net `page_load` function is loading twice, hence it affects my page performance. Does anyone know the reason it is loading more than twice.

Comment: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)) Use Page.IsPostback to correctly handle Page_Load calls.

Comment: How would that look in the code above?

Comment: If Not Page.IsPostBack Then ... code to load the timer etc .... End If

Comment: Where in the code should that be and can you show me how that would look with the code that is needed

Comment: Timers aside, I don't see how your queue subscriber can work. The page and everything in it is torn down after the response ends.